# Steps to develop an iOS app to open PSL files?

Tags: ios, outlook

In this project I've to develop an iOS application which reads the .psl files and arranges the data in the relevant section. For eg: the inbox messages from the psl file into the app's inbox folder and so on.
Can anyone guide me regarding the steps? And how would my project proceed also tell the workflow of this whole process.

Comment: please read the guideines for posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you're going to have to tackle is to figure out how to get the file onto the phone.  If you're getting it from the web; you could register as a sharable-target for that file type, or you could potentially integrate the DropBox api or something similar.

Once you have the file; you'll have to develop something to parse the file and use it as a datafile.  Depending on the size and complexity of the file there will be different possible approaches to this, and you'll need to figure out what's going to be performant for you.

Then you'll build view controllers that leverage your model and make awesome things happen on the phone.

Your question is extremely general; so this is a very general answer.  To me; the immediate critical questions are: how to get the file to the phone; and how to read the file format without loading the whole thing into RAM at one time?

Comment: Dear friend, getting file on the phone is not an issue, it's an option to get files on phone by connecting iphone with my computer or either use web service. Now the second question is how to parse the .pst file? Are there libraries in ios that do these things for me?

Comment: Can this all be done using hybrid application using Xamrin tools? As C# has built in libraries to parse .pst file. Well would it be a reasonable decision to go for hybrid instead of native ios?

Comment: I know very little about Xamrin; but it looks like the libraries they support can be compiled from source into different targets.  I'm guessing that you don't have the source for the PST tools; and Microsoft probably didn't compile them for the iPhone; so I'm guessing that's not going to work; unless I'm missing something.

Comment: This looks like an interesting starting point: http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/05/Outlook-PST-View-Tool-and-SDK